# Grouping List of object to list of object of another type using List.stream

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Child {
    private String name;
    private int roll;
    private int age;
    private Date dob;

   . . . .
   getters and setters
   . . . . 
  }

public class Parent {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    private List<Child> children;
   . . . .
   getters and setters
   . . . . 
  }
```

Now I have a `List<Child>` as Input. I want to group by the list based on the name and age property and generate a `List<Parent>` using the `List.stream()`. Any pointers would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The mapping between the `Parent` and `Child` class would be the `Parent.name` equals the `Child.name` and the `Parent.age` equals the `Child.age` (The properties that is used to group by);

Comment: How would you generate the `Parent`s? How do you know the `Parent` of a given `Child` instance?

Comment: I created The ```Parent``` class to be a container of the result of the group by of ```List<Child>```.

Comment: Looking at a child, how will I know who is its parent ?

Comment: I find the input incomplete in the case after EDIT. Input is a list of children and to find a child's parent, there is no parent input to compare parent.name.equals(child.name). In short, according to the information in the question, the required output cannot be obtained... To get a desired output, parent child relationship logic must be stored in the child class alone and should not be dependent of the parent object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a `Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Child>>>` via two `groupingBy` collectors:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Parent>>> grouped = 
    input.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Child::getName,
                                        Collectors.groupingBy(Child::getAge)));
```

This `Map` can be used to generate the `Parent` instances:

```
List<Parent> parents = 
    grouped.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .flatMap(e1 -> e1.getValue()
                            .entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .map(e2 -> new Parent(e1.getKey(),e2.getKey(),e2.getValue())))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Assuming the existence of a `Parent` constructor that accepts name, age and `List<Child>`.